# NoSuchMethodException: ManagedDataSource.getDriverClass() TomEE DB2 DataSource

Tags: java, datasource, ibm-midrange, apache-tomee

I try to access to a datasource which is defined in tomee.xml (with initial context). My TomEE+ 1.7.2 runs locally on my computer.

DataSource definition in /conf/tomee.xml

```
<Resource id="as400-ds" type="DataSource">
    JdbcDriver  com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver
    JdbcUrl     jdbc:as400://192.168.3.15;errors=full
    UserName    test
    Password    1337
</Resource>
```

Java-code where the exception is thrown:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Properties contextConfig = new Properties();
    contextConfig.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial",
            "org.apache.openejb.client.RemoteInitialContextFactory");
    contextConfig.setProperty("java.naming.provider.url", "http://127.0.0.1:8080/tomee/ejb");

    try {
        InitialContext context = new InitialContext(contextConfig);
        DataSource as400ds = (DataSource) context.lookup("as400-ds");
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

NoSuchMethodException StackTrace: *(thrown at the lookup method)*:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.openejb.resource.jdbc.managed.local.ManagedDataSource.getDriverClass()
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1773)
at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.JndiRequestHandler$DbcpDataSource.getDriverClassName(JndiRequestHandler.java:593)
at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.JndiRequestHandler.doLookup(JndiRequestHandler.java:276)
at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.JndiRequestHandler.processResponse(JndiRequestHandler.java:174)
at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbDaemon.processJndiResponse(EjbDaemon.java:360)
at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbDaemon.service(EjbDaemon.java:272)
at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbServer.service(EjbServer.java:86)
at org.apache.openejb.server.httpd.ServerServlet.service(ServerServlet.java:58)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

However when I try to access it with dependency injection *(@Resource)* in a stateless container it works fine.

Thank you in advance.

P. S. The original exception was ThrowableArtifact cannot be cast to java.lang.Error but this seems to be a [bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OPENEJB-2110) so I debugged it to get the NoSuchMethodException.

Comment: Well... have a look at this: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.openejb/openejb-core/4.5.2/org/apache/openejb/resource/jdbc/managed/local/ManagedDataSource.java -> there is no getDriverClass() indeed. So why is that called? Hmm...

Comment: This is valid XML, what you see is the textual value of the "Resource" node. Please comment only if you have something useful to add to questions.

Comment: Resources declared in tomee.xml have another syntax [link](http://tomee.apache.org/common-datasource-configurations.html)

Comment: so the config in tomee.xml is good (since @Resource injection works) so the issue is only for initialcontext lookup, right?  Then the issue must be with the properties you are passing into the `InitialContext(Properties)` constructor.  Have you tried the default ctor? `new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env/as400-ds");`

Comment: @aguibert I need to pass a parameter to InitialContext because it's a remote context. Otherwise I get a NoInitialContextException. I have to set a value for java.naming.factory.initial.